# error in working with json in WUP C# app

Tags: c#, json, win-universal-app

I have a problem in working with JSON. I have a published JSON on the web. The content of my JSON is this now:

```
"[{\"Column\":4,\"GroupId\":2020,\"GroupTitle\":\"نرم افزار کاربردی\",\"Average\":0.0,\"Cost\":1000,\"IconSquare\":\"~\\\\Files\\\\82\\\\Programs\\\\ProPlayer_V0.0.1.0\\\\839fcb30-3dfc-4b6f-a826-57601dad5047.jpg\",\"IconWide\":\"~\\\\Files\\\\82\\\\Programs\\\\ProPlayer_V0.0.1.0\\\\26777d6a-025d-40a8-b83a-12fcb1f97ca4.jpg\",\"Id\":3,\"NameEnglish\":\"ProPlayer\",\"NamePersian\":\"پروپلیر\",\"Size\":2.75,\"Version\":\"0.0.1.0\",\"VersionWindowsPhone\":\"ویندوزفون 8.1 و بالاتر\",\"Score\":0.0,\"Availables\":\"ویدئو ها\\r\\nموزیک ها\",\"Description\":\"برنامه خوبیه اما در حد تست \",\"Develeoper\":\" \",\"DTPublication\":\"2015-08-23T17:20:31.46\",\"Star1\":0,\"Star2\":0,\"Star3\":0,\"Star4\":0,\"Star5\":0,\"ProgramPath\":\"~\\\\Files\\\\82\\\\Programs\\\\ProPlayer_V0.0.1.0\\\\ProPlayer_V0.0.1.0.appxbundle\"}]"
```

I used Json.Net from NewtonSoft. Here is my class to convert JSON to this class type :

```
public class AppOrGame
    {
        public int Column { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public string GroupTitle { get; set; }
        public float Average { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
        public Uri IconSquare { get; set; } 
        public Uri IconWide { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NameEnglish { get; set; }
        public string NamePersian { get; set; }
        public float Size { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string VersionWindowsPhone { get; set; }
        public float Score { get; set; }
        public string Availables { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Develeoper { get; set; }
        public DateTime DTPublication { get; set; }
        public int Star1 { get; set; }
        public int Star2 { get; set; }
        public int Star3 { get; set; }
        public int Star4 { get; set; }
        public int Star5 { get; set; }
        public Uri ProgramPath { get; set; }
    }
    .
```

And here is my code to download a JSON string and then convert :

```
public async Task<string> DownloadStringsFromWeb(string uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        string res = "";
        webrequest.Method = "GET";
        using (var webresponse = await webrequest.GetResponseAsync())
        using (StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            res = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        try
        {
            var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<MainPage.AppOrGame>> (res);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return res;
    }
```

The DownloadStringsFromWeb is not the final function so I put the JSON converter in it too but I will separate them from each other. When I debug my code I get an exception on JsonConvert

```
{"Error converting value {Exact Json value I provided above}
 to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Universal4Khune.MainPage+AppOrGame]'. Path '', line 1, position 818."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"` (double quote) isn't a symbol to be escaped in `JSON` context. Fix of the issue is depends on how do you produce the `JSON`? If it is in the file, for example, just remove backslashes. To be more specific, I should know the nature of your `JSON`.

Comment: it's not my code . a Persian website want to list some windows phone apps in their website and I have to create their phone app .

Comment: here is the link of JSON file :

Comment: Your JSON data malformed. Of course, you can replace all occurrences of `\"` by the `'`, but in that case you can corrupt the data.

Comment: I tried to remove first and last (") it solve the problem . so I have to talk with web developer team to remove these characters to solve . I will let you know if my problem didn't solved . thanks.

Comment: Removing first and last `"` can't solve the problem. You have parsed the JSON because you copy the content of response and then paste it to your code as string variable. Try to paste it into file without first and last quotes and try read JSON from file and parse. You will face the same problem.

Comment: yes your right , exactly I paste response as a simple string . long way to go :D

Comment: simply solved the problem using a line to replace downloaded string :

Comment: res = res.Replace("\\\"", "\"");
Thank you :)